# How does the spell Plant Growth work in a dungeon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting

With a Ranger character I’m considering picking up the Plant Growth spell but I’m worried that it might be limited by the environments my character is often presented with.

How does the spell work where there maybe little or no vegetation? In a castle, dungeon or cave?

Answer (score 5):

The spell says:

> choose a point within range. All normal plants in a 100-foot radius centered on that point become thick and overgrown. A creature moving through the area must spend 4 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves.

It sounds like your question is: "the spell doesn't say that the plants are required in order to impede movement, so technically this spell impedes movement even without plants, right?"

That's technically correct, but I think any DM would interpret the spell to require plants to work. If you cast this spell in a place where there are no plants, you should expect the DM to tell you that the spell has no effect.

Comment: @AmethystWizard Then bring it up before you pick the spell and come to an agreement. It doesn't have to be an argument, just decide what ruling you all want to play with.